# Using google geocoding with django

Tags: python, json, django, api, geocoding

I'm trying to create a web application in django where a user can enter his postal code and then have nearby restaurants displayed. However, i can't figure out a way to get django to collect the json response from the google api call and use on my site. Ive tried looking around online for help but i can't seem to make any of them work. Can anyone see how to improve my views.py or if i need to add something into my urls.py or if there's another method. (I do not intend to store the postal code in my db btw)

**EXAMPLE OF GEOCODING JSON RESPONSE**

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4267861,
               "lng" : -122.0806032
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4281350802915,
                  "lng" : -122.0792542197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4254371197085,
                  "lng" : -122.0819521802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJtYuu0V25j4ARwu5e4wwRYgE",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "CWC8+R3 Mountain View, California, United States",
            "global_code" : "849VCWC8+R3"
         },
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

**Views.py**

```
from .forms import PropertyForm

def property_add(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = PropertyForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_property = form.save(commit=False)
            address = new_property.postcode
            url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + "'" + address + "'" + '+SG&key=APIKEY' 
            res = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
            data = json.loads(res)
            latlon = {
                'lat': geodata['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'],
                'lon': geodata['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
            }

            return Response(data, 'food/location_index.html', latlon)   
        else:
            raise Http404
    else:
        raise PropertyForm()
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
from django import forms
class PropertyForm(forms.Form):
    postcode = forms.CharField(max_length = 6)
```

**FOOD/LOCATION_INDEX.HTML**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %} 
{% block content %}
    <h2>Food places!!!</h2>
    <hr>
    {% for location in locations %}
    <h2><a href="{% url 'location-detail' location.pk %}">{{ location.name }}</a></h2>
    {% endfor %}

    <form action='' method="get">
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <p>Your current location is {{ latlon }} </p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Not clear, what particular do you want to store in DB from google API response?

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I don't intend to store anything from the response. I want to get back the user latitude and longitude from the api response and display all nearby restaurants in the vicinity. The restaurants are in my database but i don't intend to store the user location in my database.

Comment: So you need to render `lanlon` in your `food/location_index.html` template. Show this template.

Comment: latlon is your your context, not a key. See solution posted by me.

Comment: I changed it to {{lon}} and {{lat}}, however, whenever i submit my form its still not getting data from the json response and shows this on my terminal instead: GET /location_index/?postcode=382948

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing `latlon` key in your context, you have `lat` and `lon` only. Try:

```
<p>Your current location is lon: {{ lon }} lat: {{ lat }}</p>
```